# Active Directory authentication for Non-Domain users

Tags: iis, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have a web application using windows authentication. I also want to authenticate non-domain users against AD. Can I have domain members can enter site directly, and non-members enter their domain username and password.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this but you probably want to have 2 distinct web applications running accessing a similar set of application code.

- Web application 1 is configured to use Windows authentication.
- Web application 2 is configured to use Forms authentication. You need to have some additional code in this application which allows a user to authenticate themselves using LDAP against the active directory. This code is placed in an authentication provider if you use ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using ASP.NET, you can [write a custom provider](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050216.htm) that first auths against your AD, then a non AD store.

Or you can [use multiple providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx), `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` and then for example `SqlMembershipProvider`.

Comment: Pretty sure this will require you to use Forms Authentication however.